# Method reference to anonymous class constructor

Tags: lambda, java-8, method-reference

Is it possible to get a reference to the constructor of an anonymous class?

For example:

```
void someMethod(Function<String, SomeInterface> factory)
```

could be used as:

```
someMethod(SomeClass::new)
```

or

```
someMethod(str -> new SomeInterface(){...});
```

In the second case I used a lambda expression but I want a function reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can't.

From the [java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html):

> There are four kinds of method references:

- Reference to a static method `ContainingClass::staticMethodName`
- Reference to an instance method of a particular object `ContainingObject::instanceMethodName`
- Reference to an instance method of an arbitrary object of a particular type  `ContainingType::methodName`
- Reference to a constructor   `ClassName::new`

None of these match with the anonymous class constructor.

---

If you really want a method reference, you could write another method and reference it:

```
SomeInterface createSomeInterface(String str) {
    return new SomeInterface(){...};
}

someMethod(this::createSomeInterface);
```